# Como evitar sobre escritura de una List<Object> dentro de un for(Object[] ) con map

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Tengo una lista tipo `List<Object[]>` que se carga dinamicamente desde una consulta de la base de datos,
Como se puede corregir y evitar que con cada iteracion del ciclo `For(Object[] ..)` se sobre escriben los datos ya ingresados 
por el ultimo valor que tenga la lista map en `targetList.add(map);`

---

***Esta es el resultado de la consulta, que estoy cargando desde la base de datos***

[image: Esta es el resultado de la consulta, que estoy cargando desde la base de datos]

**Este es el metodo donde se transforma la lista recibida en una list tipo `Map<String, Object>`**

```
@GetMapping("/teacher-social-media3")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sqlObjectNativo(){

        List<Object[]> listRecibida = teacherSocialMediaServ.sqlObjectMany();
        List<Object> targetList = new LinkedList<Object>();     

        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();          


        if(listRecibida != null && listRecibida.size()>0 ){   
            for(Object[] object: listRecibida ) {   
                map.put("Id_teacher_social_media", object[0]);              
                map.put("Id_teacher_fk", object[1]);
                map.put("Id_social_media_fk", object[2]);
                map.put("Nickname", object[3]);
                map.put("Id_teacher", object[4]);
                map.put("Name_teacher", object[5]);
                map.put("Id_social_media", object[6]);
                map.put("getName", object[7]);
                map.put("Icon", object[8]);                                             

                targetList.add(map);
            }
        }else {
            map.put("MENSAJE", "NO EXISTEN REGISTROS EN BD");
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(map, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }               
        return new ResponseEntity<>(targetList, HttpStatus.OK);     
    }
```

Como se puede ver el resultado de la lista, estan sobre-escritos todos los valores por el ultimo que tenia la lista map dentro del ciclo For(Object[] ..)

```
[
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    }
]
```

***Muchas gracias por sus opiniones que puedan compartir!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las listas se guarda una referencia a un objeto en cada posición, y como `map` siempre tiene la misma referencia al objeto entonces la lista en todas sus posiciones apunta a ese.

La solución es crear un nuevo objeto y asignarlo al `map`, así la lista apuntará a objetos diferentes.

Después de `targetList.add()` crea un nuevo objeto `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`

```
targetList.add(map);
map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos,  correcto, si funciona ahora si, ya no se repite los datos en e payload. Pero tengo una duda, al  declarar nuevamente map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); se estaria creando un nuevo object por cada iteracion del ciclo for(Objec[] ...) ? .. o se esta remplazando la posicion en memoria?. Muchas gracias por su importante ayuda.

Comment: Se crea un nuevo objeto por cada iteración. Y la referencia a esa posición en memoria se guarda en la lista.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias. Entonces si el ciclo itera 100 veces se estarian creando 100 objetos nuevos en una posicion de memoria diferente cada uno?. En terminos de rendimiento mi codigo no es bueno. Y si hay 10 usuarios conectados, se estaria consumiendo toda esa ram del servidor? Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Originalmente los datos están en `listRecibida` que  es lo que se recibe de la base de datos. Cuando se hace el mapeo y se llena `targetList` efectivamente se crean tantos nuevos objetos como los que hay en `listRecibida`.Pero después se retorna `targetList` y `listRecibida` deja de tener referencias por lo tanto en algún momento la memoria usada por `listRecibida` se libera y eso compensa el espacio de memoria usado por los objetos creados para llenar `targetList`.

Comment: Que explicacion tan buena me sirvio,  muchas @Lobos, buen dia!!